# How to speed up this slow query?

Tags: mysql

I'm having some issue with this query that seems to be too slow...

```
SELECT SUM(c)  FROM (
    (
        SELECT COUNT( id ) AS c
        FROM QueueOne
        WHERE id = my_id
    )
        UNION ALL (
        SELECT COUNT( id ) AS c
        FROM QueueTwo
        WHERE id = my_id
    )
        UNION ALL (
        SELECT COUNT( id ) AS c
        FROM QueueThree
        WHERE id = my_id
    )
        UNION ALL (
        SELECT COUNT( id ) AS c
        FROM QueueFour
        WHERE id = my_id
        )
) AS d
```

It is actually quite simple : 
QueueOne, QueueTwo, QueueThree, QueueFour
Are four queue with different type of column and unfortunately can not be squizzed to One column.

This query give us the number of all waiting queue from every Queue table.
It seems that is too slow for mysql since it log it on the slow-query.log file

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT
Here's the explain :

```
+----+--------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type  | table             | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <derived2>        | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 |             | 
|  2 | DERIVED      | QueueOne          | ref  | ID            | ID   | 4       |      |    1 | Using index | 
|  3 | UNION        | QueueTwo          | ref  | ID            | ID   | 4       |      |    1 | Using index | 
|  4 | UNION        | QueueThree        | ref  | ID            | ID   | 4       |      |    1 | Using index | 
|  5 | UNION        | QueueFour         | ref  | ID            | ID   | 4       |      |    1 | Using index | 
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union2,3,4,5>    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |             | 
+----+--------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.82 sec)
```

EDIT 2: 
A little more information, some tables have almost **15 000 000 records**

Comment: Is the `id` column indexed on all of the tables?

Comment: Please provide us an EXPLAIN also.

Comment: Are these `QueueX` tables or views (or something else)?

Comment: @Martin: Yes, I added the explain so you can see it

Comment: I would like to see the cardinalities run 1. analyze QueueXXXX; 2. show indexes from QueueXXXX; Do these for all 4 tables and post back the outputs.

Comment: @TheSquad: Also check Sorin Mocanu's suggestions in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031312/how-to-speed-up-select-count-with-group-by-and-where/1037210#1037210

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an index on `id`, and rewrite into `count(*)`

```
SELECT SUM(c) 
FROM   ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS c 
         FROM   queueone 
         WHERE  id = my_id) 
        UNION ALL 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c 
         FROM   queuetwo 
         WHERE  id = my_id) 
        UNION ALL 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c 
         FROM   queuethree 
         WHERE  id = my_id) 
        UNION ALL 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c 
         FROM   queuefour 
         WHERE  id = my_id)) AS d
```

**UPDATE**

You should also look into [parallelization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html) and [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/performance-partitioning.html)

Other benefits usually associated with partitioning include those in the following list. These features are not currently implemented in MySQL Partitioning, but are high on our list of priorities.

Queries involving aggregate functions such as SUM() and COUNT() can easily be parallelized. A simple example of such a query might be `SELECT salesperson_id, COUNT(orders) as order_total FROM sales GROUP BY salesperson_id`;. By “parallelized,” we mean that the query can be run simultaneously on each partition, and the final result obtained merely by summing the results obtained for all partitions.

Comment: @Pentium10, why would `count(*)` be faster than `count(id)`?

Comment: So looks like it only makes any difference if the column is `null`-able and that it would only apply if the OP didn't have any `where` clause from your link as then it could use a cached value. Is there any reason why it would make any difference in this case?

Comment: It doesn't have to do the null check.

Comment: It doesn't seems to have speed up the query... Hard to tell since the query is never the same speed... Is this really the best way to get SUM of count from 4 tables ?

Comment: I think indeed parallelized query is my best shot, i'll try it. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is an index for `id` in each table.

Use `count(*)` instead of `count(id)`. The result is the same as there are no null-values in the id in the result, but it doesn't have to do the check for null values.

Comment: It doesn't seems to have speed up the query... Hard to tell since the query is never the same speed... Is this really the best way to get SUM of count from 4 tables ?

Comment: Well, that's what can be done about the query. It seems slow, though. I just tested to sum up the count from 30 queries in a table with 95 million records in SQL Server, and it runs in less than a second.