# MySQL - It is possible to speed up MySQL count?

Tags: mysql, performance, count

I have a simple query like:

```
select count(*) from table
```

Can I speed up MySQL by doing:

```
select count(id) from table
```

Does this make any difference in terms of speed?

Best Regards,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031312/how-to-speed-up-select-count-with-group-by-and-where

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294/in-sql-whats-the-difference-between-countcolumn-and-count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if `id` is your primary key. `*` will simply map to your primary key. `count(id)` = `count(*)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get the count from information_schema

```
select TABLE_ROWS from information_schema.tables
where TABLE_SCHEMA = '$db' and TABLE_NAME = '$tbl';
```

Comment: Wouldn't MySql use these tables under the covers on a count(*) anyway?

Comment: count can combine with filter, group by ... but this information_schema.tables is a plain count of rows in table

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is your primary key, then no it will not, since MySql will use the primary key under the covers anyway. If id is not the primary key, then it may actually make the query slightly slower.

Answer (score 0):

If id is "not null", no it won't make any difference.

If id is nullable, then it is a different query and will not (always) produce the same result.