# GROUP BY optimization with indexing in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to optimize a `GROUP BY` query because for some reason it is taking forever.  Whats odd is that when I run a GROUP BY query on another column that has the same number of characters MySQL can do it with ease. So I have a feeling it has something to do with the data itself. This is my first question. If anyone has any suggestions on how to debug this that would be awesome.

Assuming it's just a optimization problem, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031312/how-to-speed-up-select-count-with-group-by-and-where) which recommends creating an index. I am confused about how this flow would work in my terminal

Suppose the query I am having trouble with is

```
SELECT user_id, count(uid) FROM table GROUP BY user_id;
```

Given his advice would I just run the previous query and then next the following one:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_temp ON table (uid);
```

Or would they be the same query? What is the exact flow here? Is there a step I am missing?

Comment: You need to understand what an index is. Read about it. It is a one time creation of the index and all queries that run afterwards and that use the index get speed up.

Comment: Could you please paste you table definition here? Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable` and paste the output.

Comment: you should create index on `user_id`  not `id`  : `CREATE INDEX ix_user_id ON table_name (user_id);`

Comment: Nvm that is what is being created.

Comment: `ix_temp` is a dummy name, put in anything unique. make it useful if you need the name for other purposes (like looking at it later in index analysis)

Comment: After creating this index do i use `ix_temp` to query or go about things normally?

Comment: normally just proceed and forget (for now). Meaning that by giving it a useful name, you will later not scratch your head during analysis